# Service name isn't changing in Google Cloud App Engine standard spring boot java 11 maven deploy using app.yml configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy to google cloud App Engine standard, a spring boot java 11 maven microservice using app.yml. It deploys but it deploys with `default` as service name. I want to deploy it with a custom name.

I tried to put the tag `service` in the `app.yml` file but it stills has the same name.

Here is my `app.yml` file

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F1
env: standard
service: mycustomname
entrypoint: java -noverify -jar helloworld.jar
```

and here is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cors</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cors-example</name>
    <description>Demo MS for cors</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>helloworld</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectId>miproyecto</projectId>
                    <version>helloworld</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm deploying using this command `gcloud app deploy target/helloworld.jar`

Comment: Do you have already created the `default` service?

Comment: what do you mean by that? Do I need to create a default service? in my list of services in cloud appenigine there's already a default service, because everytime I deploy my service it deploys with the default service name, I want to change that with the "service" tag in my app.yml, but still it deploys with "default" as its name

Answer (score 0):

In App Engine there must be [always a default service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/configuration-files#the_default_service) no matter what .

According to your `app.yaml` file, your attempting to deploy a service called `mycustomname` and this will create a new service called like that but you will not be able to rename the service `default` since this is not possible.

You will see the new service going to the Cloud Console -> App Engine -> Versions. Once there, there is a drop down menu to choose the other services.